# How to remove a file in a broken docker container?

Tags: docker

In a Redmine Container, I added the wrong directory, and then the container doesn't work.

```
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x64-mingw32, x86-mswin32. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x64-mingw32 x86-mswin32`.
The dependency ffi (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x64-mingw32, x86-mswin32. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x64-mingw32 x86-mswin32`.
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
Plugins in vendor/plugins (/usr/src/redmine/vendor/plugins) are no longer allowed. Please, put your Redmine plugins in the `plugins` directory at the root of your Redmine directory (/usr/src/redmine/plugins)
```

Have any method to delete the wrong directory to restore my container?

```
root@ubuntu /h/quick# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                          PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
70c90a2f7e80   redmine:21_09_27          "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 hours ago    Restarting (0) 55 seconds ago                                                                                          sad_hodgkin
b7abf8aa836b   bitnami/testlink:latest   "/opt/bitnami/script…"   5 hours ago    Up 5 hours                      0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, :::8443->8443/tcp   testlink
5d2eaa25d3fa   bitnami/mariadb:latest    "/opt/bitnami/script…"   5 hours ago    Up 5 hours                      3306/tcp                                                                               mariadb
b604851f20ec   hello-world               "/hello"                 8 hours ago    Exited (0) 8 hours ago                                                                                                 serene_sutherland
12e996be9f4d   redmine                   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   47 hours ago   Exited (1) 4 hours ago
```

I committed an image, run the container from the image with the "bash" entrypoint, delete that wrong directory, after all, create a new image "redmine:21_09_27".

But the new image runs with "bash" entrypoint always, after changing the *entrypoint* to */docker-entrypoint.sh*, any container from this image cannot run, and the logs file of it is empty.

```
root@ubuntu /h/quick# docker logs 70c90
root@ubuntu /h/quick#
```

Comment: Stop and delete the broken container, and `docker run` a new container.  It will restart from the original image.  Never use `docker commit` (can you edit the question to describe the _exact_ steps to reproduce your current issue?); instead, check a Dockerfile into your source repository and use `docker build` to build images.  If you build a broken image then you can revert the change that introduced it.

Comment: It sounds a lot like you're modifying the contents of a Docker container by hand, working in the filesystem in a running container, and using `docker commit` to capture your changes. *Don't ever do this. This isn't what Docker is for.* Any filesystem changes that need to happen inside a container need to be in the `Dockerfile` that builds the image so that your image build is repeatable.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me，yes， I changed files by hand.
Now, I know the conceptions.
For my question, I have resolved it by copy the old DB file and restore it into a new good container.
Thanks for all.